# Different ng-classes based on conditional?

Tags: javascript, css, validation, angularjs, conditional-statements

How do I modify this example to highlight `green for > 30`, `red for < 20` and `orange for remainder`?

```js
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    rowTemplate: '<div style="height: 100%" ng-class="
                                        {green: row.getProperty(\'age\')  < 30}">
                      <div ng-repeat="col in visibleColumns()"
                           class="ngCell col{{$index}} {{col.cellClass}}"ng-cell>
                      </div>
                  </div>'
};
```

[image: color-grid]

Official [plnkr for the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/fGhK5VNwFH6GNakZ1TVq) (and to run it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `orange` as default class, and apply the other classes conditionally, but in Css, the green and red should be declared after orange, so it will overwrite orange. this should do it:

```
<div style="height: 100%" 
      ng-class="{ green: row.getProperty(age)>30, 
                  red: row.getProperty(age) < 20}" 
      class="orange">
</div>
```

or use this without minding css ordering:

```
 <div style="height: 100%" 
      ng-class="{ green: row.getProperty(age)>30, 
                  red: row.getProperty(age) < 20,
                  orange: 20 <= row.getProperty(age) <= 30}" >
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhh, the comma notation. So simple now that I think about it. Thanks.